# Wi-Fi network setup suggestion for 4000 Square Feet office

Tags: network, capwap

We will be moving to 4000 Square Feet office from 2000 Square Feet office. Our current hardware is,

- Apple Router which handles 50 user load
- basic router dedicated to the conference room

As we would be moving to a new office, need suggestions for a plan on how the Wi-Fi network set up can be done for this area.

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for products or resources.

Comment: Your question is really too broad. You are currently using off-topic consumer-grade hardware. You should really get a wireless site survey that will tell you how many WAPs, WAP placement, frequencies for each WAP, and radio power for each WAP. If you want seamless roaming, then you may want to use LWAPs and a wireless controller. Please edit your question to include more details. The [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) is a good guide.

Answer (score 3):

The best suggestion anyone can offer you is to hire a professional wireless installer that will perform a survey of your office space, determining the optimal location of access points.  You can do it on the cheap with consumer grade products, but you won't be happy with the results.

Comment: We want to maintain the same wifi using WAP. We want to do this on our own, so seeking experts help here. Once we get a fair idea, we can do it ourself. that's the plan

Comment: You need wireless survey equipment to properly place the APs.